# How to mention a course name in an essay?

Tags: proper-nouns, quotation-marks, titles, italics

I searched this online, and I found only a [single site](http://talk.collegeconfidential.com/college-essays/794618-course-names-in-essays.html) with information regarding how to mention a course name in an essay.

There were two conflicting answers:

> 1. If you prefer to (or need to) say its full name, make the title in italics or underline. Quotation marks are additional characters, and less is better.
> 2. Just put it in capital letters.

Which should I follow? If my course is "Introduction to Computer Programming," which should I write?

- *Introduction to Computer Programming*
- **Introduction to Computer Programming**
- Introduction to Computer Programming

Comment: As this is a matter of style, it's considered off-topic here, but you might get some good input at http://writers.stackexchange.com ...

Answer (score 3):

This is purely a question of style, i.e. one of those conventions that may differ from field to field, but aside from that do not matter one bit to anyone at all. So ask your teacher/advisor, or check what your peers do. If nobody can tell you "always use A, never use B", then go with whatever you want. Just make sure to be consistent. Pick one style and stick to it.